# Using Oracle GoldenGate Microservices Architecture to get realtime updated data and sent to a rest api

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

I want to use OGG Microservices Architecture, to get real time updated data, and send the update to a rest api. The rest API is developed by ourselves. The REST api will accept a json data with POST and auth token. And I can check the data in that api to do some further work.

I found OGG Microservices Architecture dist server can send data to a receiver with wss, ws, ogg , etc. I want to know is there any way to send the update data to my rest api.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for sending data from Distribution Server to arbitrary REST endpoints in Oracle GoldenGate 19.1 and earlier.